# what does the 'false' parameter means when calling a JS function responding to an event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm new to Javascript and I have come across function calling based on an event 
the thing that I didn't understand is:
why is the 3rd parameter in most of the cases is always 'false', and what does it mean?

```
<script>
function start(){
    does something ...

}

window.addEventListener('load', start, false);

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer can be found here: [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indicates whether events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree.  You don't have to write it explicitly, as the default is false.
For more details:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener